# Detect whether script running inside docker container

Tags: linux, docker, sh

How can a script detect whether it is running inside a container?

```bash
#!/bin/sh
if [ ... ]; then                 # ?
  echo 'running in container'
else
  echo 'running on host'
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way with `bash` :

```
#!/bin/bash

in_docker(){
    local cgroup=/proc/self/cgroup
    test -f $cgroup && [[ "$(<$cgroup)" = *:cpuset:/docker/* ]]
}

if in_docker; then
  echo 'running in container'
else
  echo 'running on host'
fi
```

You need to convert to `sh` syntax if you don't have `bash` in your container.

Comment: Thanks Philippe. My solution works, but is not completely reliable. Is this one simply an alternative, or is it more robust, such that it is "guaranteed" to work?

Comment: I think it's slightly more robust in the sense that `/.dockerenv` could be created on host as well whereas you cannot create `/proc/self/cgroup` containing `*:cpuset:/docker/*`

Answer (score 0):

The `/.dockerenv` file always exists in a docker container, so I check that:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f /.dockerenv ]; then
  echo 'running in container'
else
  echo 'running on host'
fi
```

But note that file is an artefact of an older docker design, and could be removed in a future docker version. So this is a workaround, rather than a solution.

Comment: Please post a more robust solution and I'll accept your answer.